# mic-recorder-to-mp3 is not working for desktop as can't hear voice after saving

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement audio recording for the desktop and have used mic-recorder-to-mp3 this library for audio recording. I can record the voice but when I play it after stop , just can't hear any voice.

Here is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Questions.css';
import MicRecorder from 'mic-recorder-to-mp3';
 const Mp3Recorder = new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 });
class Question extends React.Component
{

state={
   
  Ans:'',
  isRecording: false,
  blobURL: '',
  isBlocked: false,
}

componentDidMount(){

navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
  () => {
    console.log('Permission Granted');
    this.setState({ isBlocked: false });
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Permission Denied');
    this.setState({ isBlocked: true })
  },
);
}
start = () => {
 
  if (this.state.isBlocked) {
    console.log('Permission Denied');
  } else {
    Mp3Recorder
      .start()
      .then(() => {
            this.setState({ isRecording: true })
        
      }).catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }
};

stop = () => {
 
  Mp3Recorder
    .stop()
    .getMp3()
    .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
      const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      this.setState({ blobURL, isRecording: false });
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
};



handleChange=(e)=>
{
   console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({Ans:e.target.value})

}
  render()
  {
    return(
   
   <div class="container">
      <h5>What is garbage collection in java</h5>  
          <img  class="images" src={require("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\practice45\\src\\images.jpg")} />
      
<Form>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasic" >
    <Form.Label>Answer</Form.Label>
         <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="FormControlTextarea1" rows="3" value={this.state.Ans} onChange=      {this.handleChange}></textarea>
          </Form.Group>

<audio class="audio" src={this.state.blobURL} controls="controls" />
<Button onClick={this.start} disabled={this.state.isRecording}>
  Record
</Button>
  <Button onClick={this.stop} disabled={!this.state.isRecording}>
   Stop
  </Button>
</Form>
 <Button class="submit" variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
  </div>
        )
   
     }
}


export default Question;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that your question here should include all relevant details in its description (don't link to some off-site resource which may or may not exist after some time). Also it'd be better if you could narrow down your problem further; for example if there's an error message then include it as `formatted` text in your question as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your code directly into the question instead of providing a link. Please do this yourself in the future.